# starting container process caused \"exec: \\\\\"/app/start_combined_collector.sh\\\\\": permission denied\": unknown'\n\nERROR:

Tags: docker, shell, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile

the error msg is

`Cannot start service nonJira_Processor: b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\\\"/app/start_combined_collector.sh\\\\\": permission denied\": unknown'\n\nERROR: for nonJira_Processor`

This is my dockerfile

```
ADD processors/nonjira_combined_processor_docker/start_combined_collector.sh start_combined_collector.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/start_combined_collector.sh
RUN ls -lrt
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/start_combined_collector.sh"]
CMD ["inputs"]
```

in start_combined_collector.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

java -jar $1.jar --spring.config.location=/app/properties/$1.properties
```

i have changed RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app/start_combined_collector.sh"] but know use is there any problem with my start_combined_collector.sh because i tried to give chmod +x and 777 permission but still says permission denied

thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt if `WORKDIR` is `/app` before `ADD` in first line, if not you should give absolute path to destination directory `/app/`; and eliminate filename, no need of it.

Comment: How do you start the container?  In particular, do you have Compose `volumes:` or a `docker run -v` option that mounts content over the image's `/app` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for your response , i got the issue resolved, as i was copying the shell script to app directory of container which was mounted to volumes i found out that RUN command will not do anything if its mounted to volumes so i copied the shell script to other directory called script and ran it it worked
BEFORE dockerfile

```
VOL /app
COPY start_combined_collector.sh **/app**
RUN chmod +x start_combined_collector.sh
```

AFTER

```
VOL /app
COPY start_combined_collector.sh **/script**
RUN chmod +x start_combined_collector.sh
```

as this time i am copying my start_combined_collector.sh to script directory which is not mounted to VOL it worked

Answer (score -1):

Eliminate shell script steps and try only this in `Dockerfile`:

```
ENTRYPOINT [java]
CMD ["-jar", "inputs.jar", "--spring.config.location=/app/properties/inputs.properties"]
```

If it works, this will confirm that issue is certainly with shell script. Then afterward update `Dockerfile` to this and try again:

```
COPY ./processors/nonjira_combined_processor_docker/start_combined_collector.sh /app/
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/app/start_combined_collector.sh"]
CMD ["inputs"]
```

If error persist, then share entire `Dockerfile`.

Comment: The split of `ENTRYPOINT ["java"]`, `CMD ["-jar", ...]` is a little odd to me; there's no real benefit over having a single unified `CMD java -jar ...` invocation (it is neither the "one `CMD` pattern nor the "entrypoint-as-command" pattern).  I'm not clear how this answer solves the question.